# Adding a custom logic in SQL select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have requirement where I want show a column as Carryover/new.

The logic is as below.

> if color exists in palette then mark the column 'Dev type' as new else carryover. 
>   I have tried to put the business scenario using a hypothetical table structure and simillar query.

**Pal table**

```
ID  PalName     year
1   Pal 1   2017
2   Pal 2   2016
3   pal 3   2017
4   pal 4   2016
5   pal 5   2017
```

**Color table**

```
ID  Color name  requestedpalette
1   Red         pal 1, pal 5,
2   Green       na,
3   Black       na,pal 1,pal 3
```

**Season Table**

```
ID  Color ID    Palette ID  Season name
1   1                    3  Summer
2   2                    4  Winter
```

**Query**

```
WITH masterdata AS
  (SELECT season name,
          color name,
          season.is AS SeasonID,
          color.id AS ColorID
   FROM season
   INNER JOIN color ON color.id=season.colorid
   INNER JOIN palette ON palette.id=season.paletteid
   WHERE palette.year=2017 )
SELECT colorname,
       CASE
           WHEN EXISTS
                  ( SELECT 1
                   FROM masterdata
                   WHERE ',' || color.requestedpalette LIKE '%,' || masterdata.PalName || ',%' ) THEN 'New'
           ELSE 'Carryover'
       END DevelopmentType
FROM color
```

Is there a better way to fetch the above without using `WITH`?
How to set a value of a column based on the entire result set in a SQL Query

Comment: In future, Please format you question, like I did. That makes it really readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT color,
  nvl((SELECT distinct 'New'
    FROM pal
    WHERE regexp_like(color.requestedpalette,
      '^([^,]*, *)*' || PalName || '(,.*)*$')
    AND year = 2017
      ), 'Carryover') DevelopmentType
FROM color
```

You don't have PalName in your with clause, so I don't think what you have would work as is.  Since you are only comparing the requestedpalette to the PalName I didn't join all 3 tables by ids.  If you need just palettes that have a season, then bring that table in to the subquery column.

Really, after cleaning up dataentry errors, you could just move the masterdata query into your main query as a subquery and left join it on

```
color.requestedpalette LIKE masterdata.PalName || ',%'
or color.requestedpalette LIKE '%, ' || masterdata.PalName || ',%'
or color.requestedpalette LIKE '%, ' || masterdata.PalName
or color.requestedpalette = masterdata.PalName
```

and it will work per your original design.

```
SELECT distinct colorname,
  (case when PalName is not null
  then 'New' else 'Carryover' end) DevelopmentType
FROM color
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT PalName
  FROM season
  INNER JOIN color ON color.id=season.colorid
  INNER JOIN palette ON palette.id=season.paletteid
  WHERE palette.year=2017
  ) masterdata
ON color.requestedpalette LIKE masterdata.PalName || ',%'
OR color.requestedpalette LIKE '%, ' || masterdata.PalName || ',%'
OR color.requestedpalette LIKE '%, ' || masterdata.PalName
OR color.requestedpalette = masterdata.PalName
```

Edited 16-Mar-2017 to account for PalName possibly being a substring of the PalName enclosed or not enclosed in commas in color.requestedpalette.